# Como comparar nomes de caminhos de diretórios?

Tags: c#, path

Possuo dois caminhos:

1. `C:\\anacarvalho\\Database\\Updates\\2017\\2017_04\\20170419_AC` - Caminho selecionado por um *folder browser dialog*.
2. `C:\\anacarvalho\\Database\\Updates` - Caminho que está como raiz do sistema.

Preciso de uma forma, que me diga se o caminho que foi selecionado pelo *folder browser dialog*, contém o mesmo início do caminho 2. Neste caso tem que me dizer que até o *Updates* é igual.

Alguém me pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
string caminho = "C:\\anacarvalho\\Database\\Updates\\2017\\2017_04\20170419_AC";
string raiz = "C:\\anacarvalho\\Database\\Updates";
if (caminho.Contains(raiz))
{
//Código aqui.
}
```

Ou dessa:

```
string caminho = "C:\\anacarvalho\Database\\Updates\\2017\2017_04\\20170419_AC";
string raiz = "C:\\anacarvalho\\Database\\Updates";
if(caminho.IndexOf(raiz,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
{
//Código aqui.
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FMo4NF).

Comment: Por que não é a melhor? É simples, minimalista e reaproveita a implementação da plataforma. Você tem meu upvote.

Comment: Eu havia colocado porque eu não sabia se existe uma função especifica para isso. De qualquer forma editei meu post, obrigado.

Comment: A única mudança que eu faria seria usar `StartsWith` ao invés de `Contains`, e no segundo exemplo garantir que o índice é `igual a zero` ao invés de `diferente de menos um`.